# Moving notes to iCloud

Tags: macos, notes.app

I just upgraded to mountain lion and noticed that I can only see notes in iCloud in the "Notes" application.

I have several notes related to a mail account that I would like to see on the Mac or move to iCloud.

Now:

- notes are no more visible in Mail.app (as expected)
- the notes in the mail account are visible on my iPhone and iPad but I cannot move them (there is no such functionality)
- the Notes application shows the mail account on the left pane with a sub entry "Notes" but is empty
- in the "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" preferences the checkbox "Use With: Notes" is checked

Any way to move the notes to iCloud on iOS or better getting Notes to synchronize everything on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

**Notes in Mail will be removed in iOS 6**, and iCloud only syncs notes between the notes apps.

So, Mountain Lion is just a few month ahead of iOS 6 so there is a bit of a missing link between the systems.

> You can create for every "mail.app-note" one entry in the notes app
>   from iOS and they will be synced to all your devices.

So copy and paste every entry from the Mail-Notes to a new entry in the notes app on iOS, and they appear in Mountain Lion and on your other iOS-Devices.

> **Works between iOS 5, 6 and Mountain Lion.**

Comment: Notes were never in Mail on iOS...

Comment: @BoltClock I don't think that's being asserted anywhere, but they have been in Mail.app on _Mac OS_ since as recently as 10.7 Lion.

Comment: @NOTjust -- user4304: The answer starts by saying, in bold, "**Notes in Mail will be removed in iOS 6**". I was saying that iOS never supported notes in the Mail app, not even before the Notes app was introduced, making that statement quite redundant. But on rereading the answer, I think the author meant to say "Notes in Mail *will not be synced to* a device running iOS 6"...

Comment: @BoltClock Ah yes, I read the intended meaning and completely failed to see the unintended meaning (a.k.a. the writing).